# Cannot retrieve value of req.body in server-sent events based Node ExpressJS Server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-sent-events

I am trying to send payload from sse client to sse node server. I'm receiving sse.js on React client to send payload back to server but getting JSON error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/salman/Desktop/my-sse-js/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)

[React Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWMJS.png)  [Node Express.js Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBGO0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The json file seems to have some errors, which is why JSON.parse() fails. Check it in a JSON Validator like https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/